# Why aren't I getting email notifications from eBay API?

Tags: c#, .net, email, ebay-api

I am trying to get an email when one of my items sell. However, no email ever comes. If I change it to notify me when an item is listed, that email arrives so I know my code is somewhat working. Here is my code:

```
    ApiContext apiContext= GetApiContext();

SetNotificationPreferencesCall apiCall = new SetNotificationPreferencesCall(apiContext);
ApplicationDeliveryPreferencesType applicationDeliveryPreferences = new ApplicationDeliveryPreferencesType();
applicationDeliveryPreferences.ApplicationEnable = EnableCodeType.Enable;
applicationDeliveryPreferences.ApplicationEnableSpecified = true;
applicationDeliveryPreferences.ApplicationURL = "mailto://myemail@gmail.com";
applicationDeliveryPreferences.AlertEmail = "mailto://myemail@gmail.com";
applicationDeliveryPreferences.AlertEnable = EnableCodeType.Enable;
applicationDeliveryPreferences.AlertEnableSpecified = true;

NotificationEnableType notification =
new NotificationEnableType
{
EventEnable = EnableCodeType.Enable,
EventEnableSpecified = true,
EventType = NotificationEventTypeCodeType.ItemSold,
EventTypeSpecified = true
};


apiCall.UserDeliveryPreferenceList = new NotificationEnableTypeCollection(new[] { notification });
apiCall.ApplicationDeliveryPreferences = applicationDeliveryPreferences;
apiCall.UserDeliveryPreferenceList = new NotificationEnableTypeCollection(new[] { notification });
apiCall.Execute();
```

Comment: May be in Spam folder, may be filtered by your gmail and was deleted automatically.